# How to update the xml file using java with folder space path?

Tags: java, exception

```
String filepath = "C:/UIDriverProject/UIDriverPro/Test Folder/TESTDATA/TEST.dat";
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = 
DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);
```

String filepath = "C:/UIDriverProject/UIDriverPro/**Test Folder**/TESTDATA/TEST.dat";

I'm using the FILE PATH with space - **"Test Folder"**. If i give folder without space its working perfectly but with space its saying error message like below error message.

> javax.xml.transform.TransformerException:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\UIDriverProject\UIDriverPro\Test%20Folder\TESTDATA\TEST.dat (The
>   system cannot find the path specified)    at
>   org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.createResultContentHandler(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:297)
>     at
>   org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:330)
>     at
>   org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl$transform$0.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>     at helper.click_helper.updateXML(click_helper.groovy:148)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1215)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:812)    at
>   groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:144)
>     at helper.click_helper.invokeMethod(click_helper.groovy)    at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass.invokeStaticMethod(CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass.java:46)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaClassSite.call(StaticMetaClassSite.java:53)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
>     at Script1526547459389.run(Script1526547459389.groovy:30)   at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:183)     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:108)
>     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:295)
>     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:286)
>     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:265)
>     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:257)
>     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:201)
>     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:86)
>     at
>   com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:77)
>     at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$runTestCase$0.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
>     at TempTestCase1526623462047.run(TempTestCase1526623462047.groovy:20)
>     at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyShell.runScriptOrMainOrTestOrRunnable(GroovyShell.java:263)
>     at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:518)    at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:507)     at
>   groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processOnce(GroovyMain.java:653)     at
>   groovy.ui.GroovyMain.run(GroovyMain.java:384)     at
>   groovy.ui.GroovyMain.process(GroovyMain.java:370)     at
>   groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processArgs(GroovyMain.java:129)     at
>   groovy.ui.GroovyMain.main(GroovyMain.java:109)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:109)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:131)
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\UIDriverProject\UIDriverPro\Test%20Folder\TESTDATA\TEST.dat (The
>   system cannot find the path specified)    at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)     at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)  at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:213)    at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:101)    at
>   org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.createResultContentHandler(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:287)
>     ... 51 more

Comment: Your problem is that the document builder coverts spaces to `%20` to be URL safe, yet it is not opening a URL, just a file. Does document builder supports `URL` type as input? If yes, you could try `file://C:/... ...`

Comment: please post the body of your `DocumentBuilder.parse` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this:

```
    String filepath = "C:/UIDriverProject/UIDriverPro/Test Folder/TESTDATA/TEST.dat";
    URI file = new File(filepath).toURI();
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.parse(file.toURL().toString());
```

Converting to URI object makes sure that the whitespaces are taken care for
`URI file = new File(filepath).toURI();`

Answer (score -1):

Please try modifying the code to the following, and let me know if it fixes it.

```
    File filepath = new File("C:/UIDriverProject/UIDriverPro/Test Folder/TESTDATA/TEST.dat");
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);
```

Comment: No idea, but the error states: `FileNotFoundException: C:\UIDriverProject\UIDriverPro\Test%20Folder\TESTDATA\TEST.dat`, so it must be something different

Comment: @tsivarajan could you try outputting the result of `filepath.exists()` and comment out the `parse` line for now? then we can see if it is able to create a file with the given path